# splitting string by ],[ and creating json objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am grabbing values from a `textarea` with `document.getElementById("textarea-id").value`. I believe this grabs a object of type `string`.

`var b = document.getElementById("textarea-id").value`

I will `JSON.stringify(b)` because I have quotes in `b` so this will escape the quotes.

`var c = JSON.stringy\ify(b)`

I want to test if `c` is actually a JSON object. If it is, put each JSON object in an array. (there might be multiple JSON objects)

To me the easiest way to do so would be to separate the string by the `],[` values that separate the JSON objects. I'm not sure how to separate each object by `],[` while preserving the brackets.

example JSON object:

```
[{
  "a":1,
  "b":2
}],
[{
  "c":3,
  "d":4
}]
```

Comment: Checkout the other capabilities of [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: wouldn't it make more sense to fix the source that puts invalid JSON in textarea to begin with? This sounds like an `X-Y` problem

Comment: I am not understanding what exactly you want to do. 1) You are getting some values in text area. 2) You are doing JSON.stringify(value) on entered value. Till this point if you enter 123 in text area on stringify you will get "123". I have added JSFiddle for same http://jsfiddle.net/Dnyanesh/8defqdbp/. And for more information on stringify take a look https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider ...

```
c = c.replace("],[", "]###[");
result = c.split("###");
```

... by using replace, we are changing the , between the `] [` to something unique that you can then split.